# Keyboard Only Format Painter Non-Adjacent cells Excel

Tags: excel, format

basic question but how do you in Excel use the format painter on non-adjacent cells by keyboard shortcuts only (no mouse clicks)

Thanks,

SP

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/902896/excel-keyboard-shortcut-to-double-click-on-format-painter

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that Stack Overflow is focussed on Programming. Your question doesn't seem to be about that. However, Stack Overflow has many sister sites. Your question seems more suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com) and also seems to have an answer there (see @BigBen comment). Also note that it's worthwhile to check out the respective help pages [Stack Overflow's On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see what questions you can ask here.